# How are those groups called and how do I create them?

Tags: android, user-interface

Marked in red, ie the rectangle, the title text, here "ANTEIL DER AUFRUFE" as well as the divider between the title text and the pie chart. I need

- the description
- library names

[image]

Comment: You may wish to be a bit more specific about what you need. Is it the outer rectangle? Is is the text? Is it the green chevron? Is it the round chart? Is it the colored bars that are part of the chart legend? Is it the divider line between the heading and the chart? Is it something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare updated

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty unclear what you're asking. I'll guess that you want to know how to replicate parts of the image, so I'll explain what each looks like to me.

The red rectangle appears to be some sort of take on a [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html).

Inside I'd guess that it's composed of a vertical `LinearLayout` containing firstly the title `TextView` and below that, a horizontal `LinearLayout` that contains a PieChart view and another vertical `LinearLayout` to the right with the appropriate data. (It could well be that the data is part of the PieChart view, like a legend and not actually a `LinearLayout`.)

You can actually learn to make a PieChart with Google's (awesome) custom view guide [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) but you may want to find [a library that does it for you](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

Comment: Which description do you need that is not unclear to you? Serious question.

Comment: I'm glad you're asking serious questions... why don't we take another approach? You tell me what's missing from my answer.